# Find government budget at the equilibrium level of income and there is a surplus or deficit

Tags: economics

Consider an economy in which taxes are autonomous and the following values of autonomous consumption, planned investment, government expenditure, autonomous taxes, and the marginal propensity to consume are given: Ca=1,400 Ip=1,800 G=1,950 Ta=1,750 c=0.6

Is there a surplus or deficit in the government budget at the equilibrium level of income(10250)? How much?